# calling function or returning back to main method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

after demo method is called after input is 'y' after one iteration it should again ask for continue? (y/n) Please Help!! Thnxx in advance

```
public void demo()
        {
            System.out.println("Withdrawal or deposit? (w/d) :");
            char choice = s.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Checking or Savings? (c/s) :");
            char choicetwo = s.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Amount? : ");
            int amt = s.nextInt();
        }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner  s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Child c = new Child();
        c.display();
        c.demo();
        System.out.println("Continue? : ");
        char input = s.next().charAt(0);
        while(input == 'y')
        {
            c.demo();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.println("Continue? : ");
    char input = s.next().charAt(0);
    while(input == 'y')
    {
    c.demo();
    System.out.println("Continue? : ");
    input = s.next().charAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put the variable assignment into the while loop:

```
        System.out.println("Continue? : ");
        char input = s.next().charAt(0);
        while(input == 'y')
        {
            c.demo();
            System.out.println("Continue? : ");
            input = s.next().charAt(0);                
        }
```